# SKLabelNode custom size between devices

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, sklabelnode

I'm using an SKLabelNode to display a score on a universal game. The font size is perfect for iPhone but naturally needs to be bigger for iPad. I was wondering if there is any way to change the font size just for iPad? I tried this in didMoveToView: (could be completely wrong but the only thing I could think of)

```
    if UIDevice.currentDevice().userInterfaceIdiom == .Pad {
scoreLabel.fontSize = 45 }
```

This didn't work. any ideas?? 
NOTE: I'm using a custom font not an apple font if this makes any difference.

```
let scoreLabel = SKLabelNode(fontNamed: "DS Digital")

    scoreLabel.position = CGPoint(x: size.width * 0.07, y: size.height * 0.9)
    scoreLabel.text = "0"
    scoreLabel.fontSize = 15
    addChild(scoreLabel)
    scoreLabel.zPosition = 3

    let waitScore = SKAction.waitForDuration(1.0) //add score every second
    let incrementScore = SKAction.runBlock ({
            ++self.score
    self.scoreLabel.text = "\(self.score)"}) //update score label with score
        self.runAction(SKAction.repeatActionForever(SKAction.sequence([waitScore,incrementScore])))
```

Comment: Can you paste the full code of this `SKLabelNode`? from creation to being added to the scene, please.

Comment: I have updated my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try replacing

```
scoreLabel.fontSize = 15
```

with

```
scoreLabel.fontSize = UIDevice.currentDevice().userInterfaceIdiom == .Pad ? 30 : 15
```